# Probability of winning a fantasy duel

Tags: probability

I want to find, given two fantasy characters, the probability of one winning a duel over the other. There are no draws. The characters take turns attacking each other one after the other.I know who is going to be the one starting the duel, and after the first turn as I said they alternate. For both characters I know how many attacks they make each on their turns, the chance that one of their attacks has to hit the opponent, the chance that every hit has to wound the opponent, the chance that every wound has to be blocked by the opponent external armour, the chance that every wound that isn't blocked by the external armour is blocked by the opponent internal armour, and the total number of wounds that each character can take before being defeated.

I know how to calculate the chanche of each attack wounding the opponent and I know, using this chance, that by multiplying for the number of attacks per turn I can calculate the expected damage per turn.

My problem is that both characters can miss and because of that the duel doesn't have a defined maximum number of turns.

Given this complication I couldn't find a formula to calculate the win probability of a character.

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does armor degrade upon being hit? If not, then isn't the only important defensive parameter the probability that the opponent wounds you in an attack?

Comment: The probability of taking damage seems to just be an independent roll for 1) not missing, 2) the attack wounding the opponent, 3) not getting blocked by external armor, 4) not getting blocked by internal armor. Simply multiply these probabilities together to get the chance for a hit to land. If this probability is $p$ for you, and $q$ for your opponent, then the probability of winning is something like $\frac{p}{p+q}$ (not considering who goes first).

Comment: Yes the armour is not the problem, nor is it calculating the wounding probability of an attack, as I said in the post, the problem is the win percentage. And the problem in calculating the win percentage are the fact that every turn there could be a number of wounds from 0 to the number of attacks,number of attacks can differ between characters, and the fact that the wounds that each character can take before being defeated could be different.